# Timespan AM to PM c#

Tags: c#, timespan

I am working on a project that involves shift work so I need my shifts to display correctly as time moves along. I currently have 3 shifts (shifth = start shifthe = end) as follows.  Shift1 8AM-4PM Shift2 4:01PM-12:01AM and Shift3 12:02AM-7:59AM the AM times are overriding my PM times as I am in military time so they never change it just stays at shift3.  any help would be greatly appreciated below is my code.

```
 private void shifts_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


      if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(Settings.Default.shift1h,Settings.Default.shift1m, 0) && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(Settings.Default.shift1he, Settings.Default.shift1me, 0))
        {
            txtbxname1.Text = "Shift1";
        }

           if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(Settings.Default.shift2h, Settings.Default.shift2m, 0)  && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(Settings.Default.shift2he, Settings.Default.shift2me, 0))
          {
              txtbxname1.Text = "Shift2";
          }
         if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(Settings.Default.shift3h, Settings.Default.shift3m, 0) && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(Settings.Default.shift3he, Settings.Default.shift3me, 0))
          {
              txtbxname1.Text = "Shift3";
          }
    }
```

Comment: Use Datetime instead of TimeSpan.  DateTime method will automatically handle AM/PM for you.

Comment: Did you have a specific question?  I don't see one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use if...else if ... else there will be no problem

```
if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= ...... first shift selection logic ....)
{
    txtbxname1.Text = "Shift1";
}
else if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= ....second shift selection logic...)        
{
    txtbxname1.Text = "Shift2";
}
else // everything else is the third shift
{
    txtbxname1.Text = "Shift3";
}
```

Comment: assuming shift1 < shift2 < shift3 which should be the case it makes no difference, just it is more efficient

Comment: This worked, I didn't expect it to be that simple! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to take current TimeSpan from the midnight, take minutes and compare them to the benchmark values like (I've calculated the value only for the third shift):

```
var minutes = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today).TotalMinutes;
if (minutes < 2)
    txtbxname1.Text = "Shift2";
else if (minutes < thirdShiftMinutesValue)
    txtbxname1.Text = "Shift3";
else if (minutes < firstShiftMinutesValue)
    txtbxname1.Text = "Shift1";
else
    txtbxname1.Text = "Shift2";
```